# Need help to create .docx file editor in android

Tags: android, editor, docx, doc

I have an application to view all types of document files like as doc, docx, ppt, pdf, xls, xlsx etc. I want to add editor functionality so that can edit doc file in my app like as bold text, italic, underline, text color, font size etc.

For your help I attached a link of application which has too much functionalities. I only need some function not the all. Please help me if you have any knowledge about this or any library suggestion. Thanks in advance

[Check this application on play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=softmaker.applications.office.textmaker&hl=en_IN&gl=US)

Comment: did you develop the viewer application?

Comment: Yes, I have viewer app live on play store.

Comment: @LuciferMorningStar could you explain how you did it please?